# PyGAD: How to constrain genes to sample set without replacement?

Tags: python, set, genetic-algorithm, sampling, pygad

Suppose I have an assignment problem where I need to assign riders to seats. I need to enforce the constraint that at most, one rider is assigned to any given seat and every rider is assigned one seat.

Linear programming offers a means to articulate these constraints; however, do to a non-linear objective function, a heuristic algorithm, such as Genetic Algorithms, is potentially suitable optimization model choice.

If 25 seats are available, I need a mechanism to sample these seats without replacement when genes are initialized. Further, I need mutations and crossovers to observe this constraint.

```py
gene_space = [
    {"low": 1, "high": 25, "step": 25},
]
```

My questions are:

1. Does PyGAD support this set sampling without replacement functionality?
2. If not, is there an algorithm available that can adapt randomly sampled integers and enforce this constraint?

In regards to 2, a partial solution might include using a cumulative distribution function given randomly sampled integers with replacement and in some way use the CDF to retrieve samples without replacement from the seats available. (Such an approach might be inefficient, which could potentially thwart some of the perks of using PyGAD.)

Answer (score 1):

You can set `allow_duplicate_genes=False` to prevent duplicate genes. This way, the value given to one gene will not be used by another gene.

```py
import pygad
...
ga_instance = pygad.GA(...,
                       allow_duplicate_genes=False,
                       ...)
ga_instance.run()
...
```

Comment: Hmm I’m not sure. Consider the traveling salesman problem. There are N stops, each need to be visited one time. A gene would have length N and gene[i] would represent the stop number assigned to a given stop. So every gene must contain 1…N, the only difference between genes would be in which gene index each value is found. In other words, every gene must have a first stop; but some genes will be better than others at minimizing total distance traveled. I’m not sure that allow_duplicates=False would support this use case.